# Java Jar file main class run when runs from command line, but not from Windows batch file

Tags: java, jar, classpath, program-entry-point

I'm re-using a standalone Swing-based Java class which backs up and restores mysql databases.

I've tested running it from a Windows batch file (.bat) on my dev system, and it works there.

But, if I run the batch file on a different Windows , I get a "main class not found" exception.

However, when I run the command directly on the command line, it works.

The command in the batch file to run it is:

```
java -cp lda-services.jar;bip-services-1.6.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;decryptor-1.6.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;slf4j-api-1.7.31.jar;commons-io-2.6.jar com.ilcore.util.SosaMaintenanceJFrame
```

The SosaMaintenanceJFrame class is contained in the lda-services jar.

Here's the error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.ilcore.util.SosaMaintenanceJFrame
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ilcore.util.SosaMaintenanceJFrame
```

The class is definitely in the jar file, as I've extracted it the file and seen it.

Any thoughts on why this would be happening? I need to run inside a batch file so the user can just click on it to run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Most likely explanation

Your paths are relative, which means that the batch file isn't going to work unless you run it from the right place. In general, having a batch file that has an invisible rider stapled to it with: "I break in mysterious ways if not run from the appropriate dir" is a crappy batch file - make it better.

### Better solution

Or, even better, get rid of it. You don't need batch files to distribute java programs.

Proper ways to distribute java programs:

- The modern take is very very different from what you have here: JREs are dead, you must ship an installer that does the whole thing, notably including a java runtime (no longer called a JRE, and one you ship and keep up to date if relevant). That's perhaps a bridge too far for what you're doing here. Relevant tools include jlink.
- A slightly less modern take involves jars with manifests:

Your jar file should contain a manifest. This manifest must contain 2 relevant entries:

`Class-Path: lda-services.jar bip-services-1.6.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar decryptor-1.6.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar slf4j-api-1.7.31.jar commons-io-2.6.jar`

and

`Main-Class: com.ilcore.util.SosaMaintenanceJFrame`

You can use `jar`'s `-m` switch, or just include the manifest (it's just a file in the jar): it's at `META_INF/MANIFEST.MF` and it's a text file, each line is an entry, and an entry consists of a `key: value` pair.

When a jar contains this, just double clicking the jar and running `java -jar thejar.jar` will then take care of it all: Java will load the stated jars as part of the classpath, and these, crucially, are resolved as paths **relative to the directory the jar is in**, so it DOES work when you try to launch them from elsewhere, i.e. if you do:

```
C:
CD \
java -jar "c:\Program Files\MyApp\myapp.jar"
```

it works fine, whereas that batch script would fail due to being in the wrong place.

Build systems let you define the manifest too, check your build systems docs for how to do this, it'll be easy, and there are tons of tutorials if you search the web for e.g. 'manifest executable jar maven' or whatnot.

- You can consider making a shaded jar. But I wouldn't.

A shaded jar takes all your dependencies and packs them into your main jar, so that there is only one jar. There is now no need for a `Class-Path` entry (the jar you run is obviously already on the classpath and there's nothing else to include) and your app is shipped as 'just' a single jar file.

But this is mostly a red herring: There are no consumer JREs anymore so you've made the user experience from a `D-` to a `D`. If you actually care about giving your users a nice experience, there's no getting around an installation process of some sort and once you have that, having the separate jars is no longer a problem. Separate jars are less hairy when signed jars are involved, are much easier to keep up to date, and have a significantly faster turnaround (when you build your stuff and want to ship what you built, shading takes ages, so it's nice to cut that step out). The faster your CI system tells you about failing tests, the better.

- Meet in the middle

You don't have to upgrade to modules and the like. What you can do instead is use something like [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net). The aim is to end up with a zip file along with the installation instructions: Make a dir somewhere. unzip this zip in it. Doubleclick 'myapp.exe'. Done.

The zip would contain an entire JRE, all your jar file deps, and your main app, and an exe file which launch4j made for you, that launches your app using the JRE packed into the jar. This means you know exactly which JRE is being used, and it'll work even on systems that didn't have one installed yet (which, these days, should be all of them - the notion of 'end user downloads a JRE from oracle and the user + oracle work together to keep that thing up to date and security-issue-free', is dead).

The fact that it's an EXE is nice: Now if the user e.g. alt+tabs through their apps, they get your app, with your name, and your icon, instead of 'javaw.exe' with an ugly coffee mug logo.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The problem was that I was running it as admin, which apparently somehow makes it think the jar file is not in the same directory where it is if you don't run it as admin.

Comment: I got the main and classpath working, thanks. But for some reason, when I run the batch file which runs the jar file as admin, it doesn't work, in this case saying lda-services jar not found. Double-clicking doesn't work, btw. The workaround is to run it from the command line as admin, but it it would be nice if it worked without that.

Comment: Ok, the problem was that when you switch to admin, it changes directories on you. So I just had to cd back to the original directory.

Answer (score 0):

> But when I try running it from the jar file generated by Maven, however, I get a "class not found" exception.

Even if you didn't get that error, you'd get another one unless you'd used Maven Shade, as that's the only way you're going to run that with a single jar. My guess as to why that *particular* error occurs is that the app class you're attempting to run is in fact in one of the *SNAPSHOT* jars

Comment: I updated the post to be a bit more accurate and with new information; the command actually works if I run it directly from a command line, just not from a batch file. I am specifying the dependent jars in the classpath.

Comment: Please post output of `jar tf lda-services.jar | find "SosaMaintenanceJFrame"`
Bear in mind that the batch file is not relocatable. It will only work if the current directory happens to be the one with those jars in it. [See](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/91-find-the-current-directory-in-java)